# Redesign md-select Container

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Hy

Whats an elegant way to redesign the md-select Window. For example i want to change the background and hover effects.

I already tried changing the  .md-select-menu-container in css, but this didn't work. I saw that Material adds a new Div around the md-select-menu where it has

```
style="display: block; left: 593px; top: 70px; min-width: 139.469px; font- size: 12px;"
```

thats what i want to change. 
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `md-container-class` for styling - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/PGoRWL?editors=1100)

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect):

[image]

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-margin>
  <md-input-container style="margin:50px">
    <label>Bird</label>
    <md-select ng-model="birdType" md-container-class="mySelect">
      <md-option ng-repeat="bird in birds" value="{{bird}}">{{bird}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mySelect md-select-menu {
  background: yellow;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.mySelect md-content {
  background: yellow;
}

.mySelect md-option:hover {
  background: pink !important;
}
```